# Tomcat - Directory for uploads

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, upload, path

In my Tomcat server, I wrote in web.xml two paths, in order to be able to upload files on our website. One used for temporary files, thanks to

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>path_files</param-name>
    <param-value>/myPathForTempFiles</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Another one where the file uploaded will be stored, thanks to

```
</init-param>
<multipart-config>
        <location>/myPathForFiles</location>
    ...
```

As I'm working with many persons, who use different OS (Windows, Linux and MAC), my goal is to make the path 'dynamic'. We would like to avoid changing manually the path at each SVN commit or update. How could we achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about use

```
System.getProperty(“user.home”)+File.separator+"folderName"
```

to create a relative folder path?

Comment: Thanks, it's a great tip! What about
        `<location>/myPathForFiles</location>`
It's a required field in web.xml